# Visual Studio - How to replace text preserving case

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, editor

Using the find and replace dialog in Visual Studio (2010) is it possible to replace some text but to preserve the case of the text being replaced.

ie.  I want to change 'foo' to 'bar' but in my code I have Foo, foo and FOO.  I want the replacement to be Bar, bar, BAR respectively.

Is it possible?  I suspect I need to use the regular expression functionality but I need assistance in doing so.

**EDIT**: I know I can set the match case option, but all that option does is limit the replace to text matching the case of the search term. This is how I am doing it at the moment, but it is tiresome having to do three replacements - foo, Foo and FOO

Comment: Upvote the Case Preservation Search & Replace feature request for Visual Studio at this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html

Answer (score 4):

It is - simply expand the `Find Options` area of the `Find and Replace` dialog and check the `Match Case` checkbox.

Full documentation on the dialog can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87a13zt0.aspx):

> Match case - Only displays instances of the Find what string that are matched both by content and by case. For example, a search for "MyObject" with Match case selected will return "MyObject" but not "myobject" or "MYOBJECT."

---

Edit: (following clarification)

I don't know of an easy way to do what you want. A RegEx could possibly be constructed that does this, but I suspect that doing 3 search and replace would be *faster, easier and less error prone* than a RegEx, in this case.

Comment: All that option does is limit the replace to text matching the case of the search term.  This is how I am doing it at the moment, but it is tiresome having to do three replacements - foo, Foo and FOO

Comment: +1 for faster, easier, and less error prone... regex is compelling and  can be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use "match case" = true then you can replace "Foo" to "Bar" and "foo" to "bar"